# cPanel Cannot add Addon Domain says it's already configured

Tags: apache, web-hosting, cpanel, whm

I need to add an addon domain in cPanel.

When I try to add it I get this notice:

**mydomain.com is already configured.**

How can I sort this problem out?

Comment: This is a valid question and the answer was useful to resolve my problem. Consider moving this question to serverfault.

Comment: Go figure why some people think this off topic.

Comment: I deleted the domain from Parked Domains panel, and added it back via the Addon Domains panel.Then the error “Already Exists”, even though it was not listed in the Addon Domains nor was it listed in the Parked Domains. In my case i am using shared hosting with limited addon domain (maximum 2), so i added new addon domain with different name, after successful completion, deleted that addon domain,  then i tried again with first domain and sucess....

Answer (score 8):

Make sure that the domain name does not already exist. ("Addon Domains", "Parked Domains", or on another cPanel)

If it no longer exists then delete the DNS zone for the affected domain name.
WHM >> Delete a DNS Zone >> Affected Domain.

If the domain name is not there then you can try updating the cPanel cache.
`/usr/local/cpanel/scripts/update_db_cache`

The above code would have to be ran via SSH as root, cannot be done on shared hosting.

That should resolve the problem.